# Multiple forms with file input on same page

Tags: php, jquery, forms, upload, multipart

I'm newby with jquery and have a problem with dealing multiple multipart forms on same page. I'm trying to add some data to mysql via php also uploading mp3 files at same time. Each form uses samename+PHPID. There is no problem with first form but im not getting file data when i use other forms. Can anyone help me?

JS:

```
    $(".msc_send_button").click(function(e) { // changed
     var a = this.id; // Button id
     var form = $('#'+a).parents('form').attr('id'); // Get buttons parent form id
     
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData($('#'+form)[0]); // Form Data
         
        $.ajax({
               url: '/formposts',
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: formData, 
               beforeSend: function(){
                    // change submit button value text
                    $('#'+a).html('Sending...');
                },
               success: function(data) {
                   if(data) {
                            // Message      
                            $('#info').html(data);
                            //Button Reset
                            $('#'+a).html('Send');
                   }
               },
                error: function(e){
                    alert(e);
                }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

PHP Form:

```
    <form name="music-form" id="music-form<?php echo $cont['id']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
    <input type="text" name="songno" id="songno" value="<?php echo $cont['song_no']; ?>">
    <input type="file" id="mp3" name="mp3" class="inputfile" accept="audio/*" multiple>
    <button type="submit" class="msc_send_button" id="msc_send_button<?php echo $cont['id']; ?>">Send</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change your jquery selector. I didn't see your html codes but you may have created nested forms. Maybe you can use **closest('from')** instead of **parents('form')**

```js
$(".msc_send_button").click(function(e) { // changed
  
  var buttonEl = $(this);
  var form = buttonEl.closest('form');

  e.preventDefault();
  var formData = new FormData(form[0]); // Form Data

  $.ajax({
    url: '/formposts',
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data: formData, 
    beforeSend: function(){
      // change submit button value text
      buttonEl.html('Sending...');
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if(data) {
        // Message      
        $('#info').html(data);
        //Button Reset
        buttonEl.html('Send');
      }
    },
    error: function(e){
      alert(e);
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Thankyou for reply. Problem is not find form field or getting veriables. main problem is forms are not sending file data to php except first form. All the form names and ids unique name with php veriables like form-5 , form-6. if i send veriables without file its working correctly. any idea without selector?

Comment: i figure out the problem and solve it. you were right about html codes. i've add same id name from php veriable to input file id name like form name (form-5 -> mp3-5) and its work. thank you for your time again.

Comment: Glad you fix it @KeremYILDIZ